# Как удалить элемент из xml файла по атрибуту? Symfony 4.1

Tags: php, xml, symfony

Подскажите, как можно удалить тег video по атрибуту height? Например, удалить всё содержимое тега video с атрибутом height 720. Какие есть способы?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smil title="a8e8b72798c3c7159f8d8f3af9676449e3b5dc12ac1dd782003a12fabd4ac65c">
    <body>
        <switch>
            <video src="mp4:a8e8b72798c3c7159f8d8f3af9676449e3b5dc12ac1dd782003a12fabd4ac65c/360.mp4"
                   width="640"
                   height="360">
                <param name="videoBitrate"
                       value="365000" valuetype="data">
                </param>
                <param name="audioBitrate"
                       value="96000" valuetype="data">
                </param>
            </video>
            <video src="mp4:a8e8b72798c3c7159f8d8f3af9676449e3b5dc12ac1dd782003a12fabd4ac65c/480.mp4"
                   width="854"
                   height="480">
                <param name="videoBitrate"
                       value="1600000" valuetype="data">
                </param>
                <param name="audioBitrate"
                       value="128000" valuetype="data">
                </param>
            </video>
            <video src="mp4:a8e8b72798c3c7159f8d8f3af9676449e3b5dc12ac1dd782003a12fabd4ac65c/720.mp4"
                   width="1280"
                   height="720">
                <param name="videoBitrate"
                       value="4500000" valuetype="data">
                </param>
                <param name="audioBitrate"
                       value="160000" valuetype="data">
                </param>
            </video>
        </switch>
    </body>
</smil>
```

Comment: Как насчет решения на основе XSLT?

Comment: Подробнее можно?

Answer (score 1):

Решение на основе XSLT.

Использует так называемый шаблон *Identity Transform*.

**Входной XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smil title="a8e8b72798c3c7159f8d8f3af9676449e3b5dc12ac1dd782003a12fabd4ac65c">
    <body>
        <switch>
            <video src="mp4:a8e8b72798c3c7159f8d8f3af9676449e3b5dc12ac1dd782003a12fabd4ac65c/360.mp4" width="640" height="360">
                <param name="videoBitrate" value="365000" valuetype="data">
                </param>
                <param name="audioBitrate" value="96000" valuetype="data">
                </param>
            </video>
            <video src="mp4:a8e8b72798c3c7159f8d8f3af9676449e3b5dc12ac1dd782003a12fabd4ac65c/480.mp4" width="854" height="480">
                <param name="videoBitrate" value="1600000" valuetype="data">
                </param>
                <param name="audioBitrate" value="128000" valuetype="data">
                </param>
            </video>
            <video src="mp4:a8e8b72798c3c7159f8d8f3af9676449e3b5dc12ac1dd782003a12fabd4ac65c/720.mp4" width="1280" height="720">
                <param name="videoBitrate" value="4500000" valuetype="data">
                </param>
                <param name="audioBitrate" value="160000" valuetype="data">
                </param>
            </video>
        </switch>
    </body>
</smil>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="video[@height='720']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Выходной XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<smil title="a8e8b72798c3c7159f8d8f3af9676449e3b5dc12ac1dd782003a12fabd4ac65c">
  <body>
    <switch>
      <video src="mp4:a8e8b72798c3c7159f8d8f3af9676449e3b5dc12ac1dd782003a12fabd4ac65c/360.mp4" width="640" height="360">
        <param name="videoBitrate" value="365000" valuetype="data"/>
        <param name="audioBitrate" value="96000" valuetype="data"/>
      </video>
      <video src="mp4:a8e8b72798c3c7159f8d8f3af9676449e3b5dc12ac1dd782003a12fabd4ac65c/480.mp4" width="854" height="480">
        <param name="videoBitrate" value="1600000" valuetype="data"/>
        <param name="audioBitrate" value="128000" valuetype="data"/>
      </video>
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваши старания, уже решил путём приведения к массиву xml, затем рендера через шаблонизатор twig